# Android Volley NetworkDispatcher

Tags: android, android-volley

My application loads alot of data from a webservice and I'm using the volley library for the network request. Volley is stacking NetworkDispatcher objects and ends up crashing the application.

I made a test with DDMS Heap Dump (http://spragucm.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/debugging-android-project-ddms-heap-dump-in-eclipse/) and it revealed volley is instatiating 92 objects of "com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher".

Why is volley stacking NetworkDispatcher objects?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation clearly states that Volley is not suitable for downloading large data. You can consider using alternate such as the DownloadManager.

> Volley is not suitable for large download or streaming operations, since Volley holds all responses in memory during parsing. For large download operations, consider using an alternative like DownloadManager.

Reference: [Android Volley Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: I know this is an old question but can you please quantify what "large data" is? When I imagine "large data" I think of 100MB or more... However I am seeing similar things as the OP when both uploading and downloading JSON of size between 300KB - 1MB