# Volley forced cache - how to achieve it for caching string from a url?

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

With reference to the Question and Answer at - [Android Volley + JSONObjectRequest Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781244/android-volley-jsonobjectrequest-caching)

I am implementing volley and facing issue of the cache (forced caching) at the APP end and am unable to do it.

Answer suggested by oleksandr_yefremov, is to create a method. I am unable to use that method. Can anybody help in understanding and to use is in fetching string from a url and cache it.

Here is the code suggested by oleksandr_yefremov

```
public class MyRequest extends com.android.volley.Request<MyResponse> {
...

@Override
protected Response<MyResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    String jsonString = new String(response.data);
    MyResponse MyResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyResponse.class);
    return Response.success(MyResponse, HttpHeaderParser.parseIgnoreCacheHeaders(response));
}

}
```

Please guide me to use it for string fetch and cache.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in the method `parseNetworkResponse` you do not have access to `Volley cache`, so you can not cache your result, what should you do?

at the function `onResponse` get the `Volley cache` from your `request queue` and then change your `response` to `string` (because now it is json) and then put it by the key value of your request `URL`.