# Android Volley JsonObjectRequest returns same response every time on mobile data

Tags: android, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I am using [Volley JsonObjectRequest](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json) to get data from server.

code snippet:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

But I am getting same `JSONObject response` every time on mobile data connection.

**Note:** It's work perfectly on WiFi connection.

Is anyone facing this issue ? any solution ?

Comment: Can you clarify that? Get same response is not the expected one? Can you post the server Url or server code for checking? Or you mean the response cached?

Comment: Yes I have checked that url with other HTTP Requester client and that is not server issue. Volley returns old response every time in mobile data only.

Comment: Try call request.setShouldCache(false); to check if it works

Comment: For me it is not working with setShouldCache(false). The new file is not loaded, but the older one on cache.

Comment: @TonyL have you added `setShouldCache(false)` before adding request to queue?

Comment: Yes I did. From the PC browser I can see the updated file, but the android emulator always return the old values. I cleared the app cache and reinstalled with no success

Comment: I tried changing the date by increasing it and then i corrected the date again but the volley seems to get the last request which will always depend the date so i guess you should always use request.setShouldCache(false);

Answer (score 22, accepted):

@BNK `request.setShouldCache(false);` worked for me. It's issue of volley cache management.

I assume that, when a request is sent:

- It would hit the cache first and send that to `onResponse`
- then when the results come through from the remote server it would provide it to the `onResponse`

If you use any of the default Request classes implemented in volley(e.g. StringRequest, JsonRequest, etc.), then call `setShouldCache(false)` right before adding the request object to the volley `RequestQueue`

```
request.setShouldCache(false);
myQueue.add(request);
```

You can also set **expiration policy** for cache.

[See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781244/android-volley-jsonobjectrequest-caching)

Comment: I think you should set the small softExpire instead, please read [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897189/android-setup-volley-to-use-from-cache)

Comment: you saved my another day.

Comment: Man you saved my life. Thanks!!